# Using custom data in TypreScript+Cypress

Tags: typescript, cypress

I have to send data like this to my tests. The data file has two records. Note that the key values are different for the 2 records in this JSON file. For eg: the first record has `'CompPhoNum'` and the second record has `'CellPhoNum'`. The tests are written in TypeScript. The automation framework I'm using is Cypress.

I'm trying to figure out if using Cypress fixtures to pass data to the files is a good option or if I could just store custom data in a file and retrieve the custom data values from that file .

```
[
  {
    "FirstName": "Leandro",
    "LastName": "Pereira",
    "CompanyEmail": "leandro.nares@company.com",
    "ComPhoNum": "991549450",
    "CompWebSiteUrl": "www.kyz.com.br"
  },
  {
    "FirstName": "Paulo",
    "LastName": "Nares",
    "PersonalEmail": "Paulo.nares@gmail.com",
    "CellPhoNum": "000000000",
    "HomeAddress": "www.paulo.com.br"
  }
]
```

Comment: Do you want to read each key value in your test spec or set them via the test spec file

Comment: Thanks for responding . I want to read each key value in my test spec. I'm not setting them via the test spec file.